# Maximum perimeter of a rectengle given the diagonal

Tags: geometry

Find the maximum perimeter of a rectangle with integer sides whose diagonals have length at most 24.

I know that the correct answer is 12.

But... Can someone help me by stating the formula for this?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your answer is wrong. A rectangle with sides 8 and 22 has perimeter 60, and diagonals of approximate length 23.4. Thus the maximum perimeter is at least 60.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=(2,2)$ and $y=(a,b)$. If $||y|| \le 24$, then, by Cauchy Schwarz:

$2a+2b=<x,y> \le ||x||*||y|| =2 \sqrt{2}||y|| \le \sqrt{2}*48$.

Your turn !

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ and $b$ be the lengths of the sides of your rectangle and let $c$ be the length of the diagonal. Then we have by Pythagoras $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. We want to maximize the perimeter which is equal to $2a+2b$. Therefore our maximization problem is
\begin{align}
&&\max{} &2a+2b \\
&&\text{given } &a^2+b^2 \le 24^2 \\
&& & a,b\in\mathbb{N}
\end{align}
Usually there are no exact ways to solve an integer maximization problem. In most cases you need an optimization algorithm. In this case, since the problem is small, you could just try all values in a computer program.

Another approach: If we drop the integer condition, then Lagrange gives us $a = b = 12\sqrt{2} \approx 16.97$ and a perimeter of $48\sqrt{2} \approx 67.88$, which gives us an upper bound. Trying integer solutions close to the general solution we can try $a=16$ and $b=17$ to get a perimeter of $66$. Since any integer solution will produce an even perimeter and $66$ is the largest even number $<48\sqrt{2}$ we have found the optimal solution.